# How can I decide which client can see a page and which not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a multi step form and have validated it with java and php but yet I want that after submitting and redirected to my desired page my client to be the only one to see the redicted page , not like he can just copy the link and give it to somebody and than others could se that page to I don't want that .

So to be more specific I want it so that after my client submits his form to get a kind of an id or something that can see or checked from my redirect page and than the redicted page to oppened up to him and that only for a specific time.

Comment: I'm assuming you already have a user registration system or some way to identify the client. Just make sure you check that the person accessing the page with the given id is logged in and a proper user before rendering the page, otherwise throw "Access forbidden" or something similar.

Comment: before submitting my form the user is not registered in our user account database so could it work maybe with ip or something, i need that just for those 2 pages.  1 submit page 2 destionation page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several ways that you can do this, but it also depends on the environment. You can create a session on form submission with a parameter that will be checked when redirecting to the page, then checking if the parameter exists after redirection as @michaelb suggested.

**form.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['form_finished'] = true;
header('location: /../mycode.php');
```

**Then on destination.php...**

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['form_finished']) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To redirect once form is submitted you will need to do something like this.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//form processing code//
    if ($no_errors) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['form_finished'] = true;
        header('location: /../mycode.php');
    }
}
```

If your users are logged in, and you are looking for a more permanent and secure solution, you could add a field to the database which you check on destination.php instead of the $_SESSION() variable.

Comment: This looks very logical one question through the [header 'location: destination.php'] in destination you mean the redictet page ? thank you

Comment: I'm getting and syntax error in the first code [ header 'location: destination.php';] ?

Comment: yes, destination.php would be the page you want to redirect to.

Comment: yes i wrote the path there but i get that syntax error again [ header 'location: /../mycode.php';]

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in mysite.biz\httpdocs\new\apply_now.php on line 8

Comment: So apply_now.php is the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: the 8 line is exactly the  header 'location: /../mycode.php'

Comment: Ok, it is because I missed a quote, I will correct my answer.

Comment: no its the site where the form is

Comment: There aren't any syntax errors in the code I gave you, it may be a line close to it. Without being able to see what you have now it's hard to say.

Comment: Post your code in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62217/discussion-between-new-logo-and-eternalhour).

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information about frameworks used, etc., try using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

In the final form processing page, do something like:

```
$_SESSION['form_finished'] = true;
```

To "make a note" that this person has finished the form. In the final "submitted" page, ensure that the person has finished the form with something like:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['form_finished'])) {
    // Redirect to error page, display error message, etc
}
```

Comment: i will give it an eye besides this thanks